# mockjax: include/exclude urls for mockjax

Tags: url, mockjax

I am using bootstrap theme plugin. it has mockjax used internally. in my application in one page iam keeping some some javascript files with src attribute. so mockjax is mocking these js files and my page is not working. how to avoid this mocking for this page.

Comment: Which plugin are you using? Is it a plugin for twitter bootstrap or something else? If they are using it internally you might not be able to alter the settings of the Mockjax plugin. Please provide links to whatever you are using, and add some code for how you are using it. Perhaps there is a plugin option to disable Mockjax?

Comment: it got resolved. i disabled that